# Epson JavaPOS ADK Install not completing

Tags: epson, javapos

In trying to install the Epson JavaPOS ADK the program never finishes. Looking at the log file seems that the program is looking for files that do not exist, and therefore cannot manipulate them. After installation "completes" the file `C:\opt\EpsonJavaPOS\Uninstall_Epson JavaPOS ADK_1.14.0.0\.com.zerog.registry` is created. Not sure what I've done to mess this up.

### Log exerpts

```
Modify Text File - Single File:   No Target Chosen
                      Status: ERROR
                      Additional Notes: ERROR - Unable to locate ASCII text file to be manipulated.  Deferring...

Modify Text File - Single File:   No Target Chosen
                      Status: ERROR
                      Additional Notes: ERROR - Unable to locate ASCII text file to be manipulated.  Deferring...

Install Action:           InstallAnywhere Variable
                      Status: SUCCESSFUL

Install Action:           InstallAnywhere Variable
                      Status: SUCCESSFUL

Check Disk Space:         /opt\EpsonJavaPOS
                      Status: SUCCESSFUL
                      Additional Notes: NOTE - Required Disk Space: 40,268,671; Free Disk Space: -1

Install Action:           Jump To: Next Unit Package Con't -- Prev: NO JUMP
                      Status: SUCCESSFUL

Modify Text File - Single File:   SetupPOS.properties
                      Status: ERROR
                      Additional Notes: ERROR - Unable to locate ASCII text file to be manipulated.  Deferring...
```

### System Setup

- Windows 10
- Java 1.8.181
- JavaPOS ADK v1.14W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are bug fixes that may be involved in [JavaPOS ADK 1.14.3W](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5298&scat=40&pcat=3).

> [Bug fix]
>   - The bug is fixed that the installation of JavaPOS ADK fails in the latest Java VM on Windows10.

The latest version is 1.14.6 W, so please try it.
[EPSON JavaPOS ADK (for Windows OS) Ver. 1.14.6W](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5666&scat=40&pcat=3)

Comment: How about for linux? it seems 1.14.5 has bug in running the setup

Comment: And the installer too. Their installer has error in code.

Comment: @AyukNayr, The latest version is [EPSON JavaPOS ADK (for Linux OS) Ver.1.14.6L](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5667&scat=40&pcat=3), and the contents you say are not listed in the Bug fix list. If it still occurs even if you change to the latest version, please contact EPSON.

Comment: How do I contact them

Comment: The method is described on the site of EPSON in your country. It looks like the Philippines, so it will be [here](https://www.epson.com.ph/contact#zZwf9e7VKRYqI1WW.97).

Comment: Thanks.
Anyway I used the latest version which is 14.6.

Now when I execute SetupPOS, the error is Could not find or load main class.com.epson.pos.SetupPOS.SetupPOS

Help much appreciated :)

Comment: what could be the reason for this? hmm

Comment: EPSON may have forgotten to describe the bug fix.

Comment: I thought I used 14.6 but it was 14.5.
Bug fixed in update 14.6.  

versions for ubuntu not working.
1.14.1
1.14.2
1.14.3
1.14.4
1.14.5

Answer (score 0):

for me, i found out that the installer does not play nicely with Java 8 and Windows 10. After I used Java 7 as the parameter for LAX_VM, it installed correctly. You may need to switch to another user if the installer keeps skipping installation steps though.

Comment: I just found out, to avoid skipping installation steps by Epson JAVAPOS installer, you can delete the directory named `Zero G Registry` present in `C:\Users\<YOUR_USER>` folder. After deleting this, if you run the installer, it won't skip steps anymore. Just putting this out so if anyone else has this issue, it would help them.